# How to access photo EXIF in pictures taken from camera in iOS 4.0+?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, camera, exif

How do I access the EXIF info in a picture from the camera taken using the new 4.0/4.1 APIs?

I use `_captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection_` to take the picture and:

```
[AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
```

to get the jpg data but how do I extract the EXIF?

The doco makes references to `imageDataSampleBuffer` containing EXIF (I can see it in there if I examine the variable in the console):

"*The buffer attachments may contain metadata appropriate to the image data format. For example, a buffer containing JPEG data may carry a `kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary` as an attachment*"

But I can't figure out how to manipulate a CMSampleBufferRef to acces it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Image I/O Framework which was introduced in iOS4 allows one to read EXIF properties from a picture according to the documentation.

Link: [CGImageSource Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageSource/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001399) - have a look at the `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex` function.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/) library could be of assistance.

Comment: Correct, that library could be used but now that Apple supports EXIF natively I'd rather use native APIs to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to actually save the image to the Photo Library so that the EXIF data is added to the image. After that you can use ALAssetLibrary to retrieve the image along with the EXIF info.

Comment: Nah, you can use the Image I/O Framework as Yannick mentions, no need to save it to the library.