# How to get a NSDATE from UIImage?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, metadata, nsdate

How do i get a date or metadata from a UIImage in this case:

```
//UIImagePickerControllerSourceType
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

//delegate return
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

// po info in console -> there is no metadata of the image where i can find the date
// Has anyone an idea how to get it?

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to EXIF metadata in the image (which includes date information), you can see this question for information on how to access it:

[How to access photo EXIF in pictures taken from camera in iOS 4.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673062/how-to-access-photo-exif-in-pictures-taken-from-camera-in-ios-4-0)

Comment: That did the job. Is this static lib allowed by Apple?

Comment: I think you should be fine to link with a static lib. Xcode has an iOS template for a static lib and I'm pretty sure a lot of apps on the store will want to use libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The info dictionary contains a key called "UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata" which is another dictionary. Just NSLog allKeys of that to get the date key.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *metadata = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];
NSLog(@"%@",metadata);
```

Choose what you need from metadata.

Comment: Oke thanks, i have notice that it is in the info dict when the sourceType is set to Camera. But when it is set to Library this is the content of the dict:

`code
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb) po info
{
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image";
    UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "<UIImage: 0x647b420>";
    UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000115&ext=JPG";
}`

Comment: UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata - This key is valid only when using an image picker whose source type is set to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera, and applies only to still images. - is (unfortunately) what Apple documentation says. I think the answer then is in @GregInYEG post.