# How to get information from UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a NSDATE from UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276456/how-to-get-a-nsdate-from-uiimage)

Hi I need to get some informations from an UIImage. For example I need to get the date when the photo has been taken etc.
I don't have any idea of how to do that.

Any helps?

Comment: are you referring to an image being taken from Camera ??

Comment: yes I need the information of that photo. Date, weight etc...

Answer (score 2):

You want to use CGImageSourceRef rather than UIImage, see [the CGImageSourceRef documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageSource/Reference/reference.html). You then use code like

```
NSDictionary* metadata = (NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL);
```

to get the meta data. There is a detailed tutorial [here](http://caffeinatedcocoa.com/blog/?p=7).

Comment: I found that in this delegate method 

   - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

there is all what I need. 

Thanks for your answer btw. :)