# Getting details from photo

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, camera

I'm working on an app that involves getting information from a photo that is taken with the in-built camera of the iPhone.

```
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

I would like to get the info on date/time of capture as well as the coordinates of the place of capture. Any idea how I would do this?

Comment: It is called EXIF data, here is a related post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673062/how-to-access-photo-exif-in-pictures-taken-from-camera-in-ios-4-0

Answer (score 0):

Using the Asset framework you can do this:

```
  #import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

  ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
  NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

  [library assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
    NSLog(@"TIMESTAMP: %@", [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate]);
  } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"FAIL");
  }];
```