# How can I get embedded GPS and geolocation data of images in iPhone image Gallery

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uiimage, metadata

I wanna use  embedded GPS and geolocation data of images in iPhone image Gallery. How can I get latitude and longitude of the place, where image was taken.

Thank you in advance..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1238838/468724

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure how this can be done programmatically, but I'd look into how to extract exif data from an image. Maybe [this](http://blog.depicus.com/index.php/2011/05/07/getting-exif-data-from-images-on-ios/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673062/how-to-access-photo-exif-in-pictures-taken-from-camera-in-ios-4-0) will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos),

U can reference that.
^-^

Answer (score 0):

Getting the destination is easy.
Here is an [example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_map) showing how to get the geolocation.

Let me know if you have a script to combine the two.